# iPhone, mobile-web; questions with active bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounty, asking-questions, user-interface, mobile-web

I was perusing the stack site on my iPhone and realized when looking though the questions I couldn't locate a sort option for questions with active bounties. Does it exist on for mobile or has anyone else experienced issues finding it?

Answer (score 4):

You can filter question lists by 'featured' to list those with a bounty:

> [image: mobile web questions list with featured filter]